# How do I change my home folder in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I've installed cygwin on my work computer. The problem is that my my computer is part of a domain and cygwin is using my network home folder as my home folder every time it launches. I would like to have my home folder set to a folder on my local machine instead.

How do I do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225764 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all make sure your domain user is added to `/etc/passwd`:

```
mkpasswd -d >> /etc/passwd
```

Then just edit `/etc/passwd` and let it point to your desired directory. For example my entry looks as follows:

```
myuser:unused:11555:10513:U-DOMAIN\myuser,S-1-5-21-3223550679-1857247031-121334384-2459:/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/cygwin/home:/bin/bash
```

This places the cygwin home directory within my roaming profile folder within my user profile.